# What is sourcing my shell script?

Tags: shell-script, zsh

I have a `.zshrc` and a `.zshenv` in my home directory.  I added a new command to my `.zshenv` that I discovered was being run at least 3 times.  I realized that I was accidentally `source`ing it from the `.zshrc`, so I removed that line, but it's still being run twice.

I've tried echoing `$0` and `$_` in the script, and I get `(~/.zshenv) (~/.zshenv)` for the first pass, and `(30) (zsh)` for the second.  What could that mean?  Is there a better way to get a "stack trace" showing my caller?

Comment: 30 is probably a line number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you invoke `zsh` you can debug what's going on by using the `-x` switch. It's similar to `bash`'s `-x` switch, where it shows each line as it's executed along with any results.

```
$ zsh -x
    ...
+/etc/profile.d/mc.sh:3> alias 'mc=. /usr/libexec/mc/mc-wrapper.sh'
+_src_etc_profile_d:9> i=/etc/profile.d/PackageKit.sh
+_src_etc_profile_d:10> [ -r /etc/profile.d/PackageKit.sh ']'
+_src_etc_profile_d:11> . /etc/profile.d/PackageKit.sh
+_src_etc_profile_d:9> i=/etc/profile.d/qt.sh
+_src_etc_profile_d:10> [ -r /etc/profile.d/qt.sh ']'
+_src_etc_profile_d:11> . /etc/profile.d/qt.sh
+/etc/profile.d/qt.sh:9> [ -z /usr/lib64/qt-3.3 ']'
+_src_etc_profile_d:9> i=/etc/profile.d/udisks-bash-completion.sh
+_src_etc_profile_d:10> [ -r /etc/profile.d/udisks-bash-completion.sh ']'
+_src_etc_profile_d:11> . /etc/profile.d/udisks-bash-completion.sh
+/etc/profile.d/udisks-bash-completion.sh:3> [ -z '' ']'
+/etc/profile.d/udisks-bash-completion.sh:3> return
+_src_etc_profile_d:9> i=/etc/profile.d/vim.sh
+_src_etc_profile_d:10> [ -r /etc/profile.d/vim.sh ']'
+_src_etc_profile_d:11> . /etc/profile.d/vim.sh
+/etc/profile.d/vim.sh:1> [ -n '' -o -n '' -o -n 4.3.10 ']'
...
```

The output can also be redirected to a file for later review.

```
$ zsh -x 2>&1 | tee zsh.log
```

This will appear to hang at the end, just <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to stop it, and then check out the resulting log file, `zsh.log`.

Comment: Apparently, in this case, `/etc/zshenv` was `source`ing `~/.zshenv`, but (as far as I can tell) I think `zsh` will source that file as part of its startup.  The trace showed the source invocation from `/etc/zshenv`, then just started right back in on `~/.zshenv` a second time!

Comment: @Coderer - yes a fair amount of files get sourced automagically thanks to `/etc` and `/etc/profile.d` on some systems.

Answer (score 0):

Have you applied changes with `source ~/.zshrc`? Or logged out and back in for the changes to take effect.

Comment: This sounds more like a comment than an answer.